# Botpress binaries are no longer available on the official site

Tags: botpress

Since Botpress has released the Botpress Cloud version, it is very hard to find in the oficial site the download link to get the binaries for Windows, Mac, Linux or the Docker Image.

Every link to get Botpress guide the user to try the cloud version, or to GitHub to build it from source.

Does anyone know if the binaries are still available for download?

Answer (score 3):

After reading the README.md file in GitHub, I found they have moved the download links to this new subdomain:

https://v12.botpress.com/

There you will find all the download links:

[image]